# streamlit change formatting type for big integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit, dtype

Suppose I have a simple `pandas` dataframe and I want to show these values inside a web app using `streamlit`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1174505943511396352, 2414501743231376356]})
st.table(df)
```

Printing the dataframe gives me:

```py
>>> df
                     a
0  1174505943511396352
1  2414501743231376356
```

But the result inside the web app would be shown like below:

[image: result]

As you can see the values are not correct, and they are somehow rounded and **the original value is not displayed**.

#### What have I done?

- I tried changing the `dtype` of my dataframe, but it did not work:

```py
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(np.uint64)
st.table(df)  # no changes!
```

- I also tried `style.format`, it did not work either:

```py
func = lambda x: np.uint64(x)
df = df.style.format({"a": func}
st.table(df)  # I got errors as below
```

Error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\a.tabarayi\desktop\analyze-clustering-results\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 349, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\a.tabarayi\Desktop\analyze-clustering-results\src\app.py", line 90, in <module>
    st.table(x)
  File "c:\users\a.tabarayi\desktop\analyze-clustering-results\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\data_frame.py", line 120, in table
    marshall_data_frame(data, table_proto)
  File "c:\users\a.tabarayi\desktop\analyze-clustering-results\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\data_frame.py", line 150, in marshall_data_frame
  File "c:\users\a.tabarayi\desktop\analyze-clustering-results\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\elements\data_frame.py", line 169, in _marshall_styles
    translated_style = styler._translate()
TypeError: _translate() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'sparse_index' and 'sparse_cols'
```

**Any help would be appreciated, thanks!**

#### Edit:

The following solution seems to be working for me, but let me know if there is a better approach to prevent unnecessary type casting!

```py
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(str)
st.table(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in streamlit and they have solved it. I dont know when it will be active for the "normal" users

https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/3526

https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/pull/3536

A patch will be released next week and a minor update in the next couple of weeks ([*](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/pull/3536#issuecomment-881968595)). In the meantime, you could change your requirements.txt and put

```
pandas==1.1.4
```

in it